# How are strings physically stored in Javascript

Tags: javascript

What I am looking for is how strings are physically treated in Javascript. Best example I can think of for what I mean is that in the Java api it describes the storage of strings as:

`String str = "abc";" is equivalent to: "char data[] = {'a', 'b', 'c'};`

To me this says it uses an array object and stores each character as its own object to be used/accessed later (I am usually wrong on these things!)...

How does Javascript do this?

Comment: it becomes a String object, however, you can get characters as an array as well: `var str = "Hello"; console.log(str[0]); //shows "H"`

Comment: they are "physically" stored, they are digitally stored obviously. while you can use the array access [] to get individual characters , strings are not arrays or char in javascript there is no char type and string doesnt have the methods related to array manipulation.

Answer (score 3):

Strings are [`String` objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String) in JavaScript. The `String` object can use the `[]` notation to get character from a string (`"abc"[0]` returns `'a'`). You can also use the `String.prototype.charAt` function to achieve the same result.

> **Side node:** `var a = 'abc'` and `var b = new String('abc')` are not the same. The first case is called a primitive string and get converted to a `String` object by the JavaScript parser. This results in other data types, calling `typeof(a)` gives you `string` but `typeof(b)` gives you `object`.

Comment: Thanks all - some good replies - so what does each character look like in a JavaScript string - is a string still an array of 'characters' in JS like in Java?

Comment: no, it's just a string. It can be that the string is saved as an array inside the String object, which makes the iteration possible, but I don't know if that's true (my knowledge of the JS parser doesn't get that far..)

Comment: Thanks - can anyone else offer any info?

Comment: You can view the actual code V8 uses to construct its string object here: http://v8.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/src/string.js If you want more details as to how a string is handled in memory you'll need to dive into the object.h and object-inl.h

Comment: Thanks! that was just what I was looking for...I guess it could be rather browser specific...!

Answer (score 0):

Strings are stored in the same format in javascript as other languages stores.
Suppose var word = "test" than at word will be as an array of characters and the 't' will come at 0th position and so on.

The last iteration as taking 'word.length' will return undefined. In other languages, it returns as '\0'.